# Code for 4-Digit 7-Segment Display: Why doesn't code work for 2 of 4 digits?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm

I have written 2 functions (gpio_write & gpio_set_function) to be able to control the digits and segments of a 7-Segment Display (Common Anode LED), that is connected to my RPi via Bipolar Junction Transistors: Collector to common power, base to RPi pins via 1 kOhm resistor, and emitter to digit nodes on the display (image here).

[image]
The segments are connected directly to pins on the RPi.

The code successfully lights up digits 1 & 3, (and all segments) but digits 2 and 4 do not light up. I need some help figuring out why that is.

I have double & triple checked the wiring, made sure the digits are connected to pins 10 thru 13, and the segments to pins 20 thru 26 (period to pin 27). I have checked the code as well, and couldn't find a problem with it. I have also made sure that each of the digits actually works by disconnecting from the RPi and lighting up each of the segments on each digit independently (Segment B of Digit 3 is burned, all the others work).

What could be another issue that would cause digits 2 and 4 not to light up? Or perhaps something IS wrong with the code?

```
#include "timer.h"
#include "gpio.h"

void gpio_set_function(unsigned int pin, unsigned int function) {
  unsigned int mask = 7;
    if ( (pin < GPIO_PIN_FIRST || pin > GPIO_PIN_LAST) || (function < GPIO_FUNC_INPUT || function > GPIO_FUNC_ALT3) )
        ;
    else{
        switch (pin/10){
            case 0:
                *GP_FSEL0 &= ~((mask)<<(3*pin));
                *GP_FSEL0 |= function<<(3*pin);
                break;
            case 1:
                pin = pin%10;
                *GP_FSEL1 &= ~((mask)<<(3*pin));
                *GP_FSEL1 |= function<<(3*pin);
                break;
            case 2:
                pin = pin%20;
                *GP_FSEL2 &= ~((mask)<<(3*pin));
                *GP_FSEL2 |= (function<<(3*pin));
                break;
            case 3:
                pin = pin%30;
                *GP_FSEL3 &= ~((mask)<<(3*pin));
                *GP_FSEL3 |= function<<(3*pin);
                break;
            case 4:
                pin = pin%40;
                *GP_FSEL4 &= ~((mask)<<(3*pin));
                *GP_FSEL4 |= function<<(3*pin);
                break;
            default:
                ;
        }
    }
}

void gpio_write(unsigned int pin, unsigned int value) {
    if ( (pin < GPIO_PIN_FIRST || pin > GPIO_PIN_LAST) || (value < 0 || value > 1) ) ;
    else {
        switch (pin/32){
            case 0:
                if (value==1){
                    *GP_FSET0 &= ~(1<<pin);
                    *GP_FSET0 |=   1<<pin;
                }
                else
                    *GP_CLR0 |= 1<<pin;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (value==1){
                    *GP_FSET1 &= ~(1<<(pin-32));
                    *GP_FSET1 |=   1<<(pin-32);
                }
                else
                    *GP_CLR1 |= 1<<(pin-32);
                break;
            default:
                ;
        }
    }
}

void main(void) {
    volatile int i;
    for(i = 10; i < 14 ; i++)
        gpio_set_function(i, GPIO_FUNC_OUTPUT);
    for(i = 19; i < 27 ; i++)
        gpio_set_function(i, GPIO_FUNC_OUTPUT);
    while (1){
        for(i = 10; i < 14 ; i++)
            gpio_write(i, 1);
        for(i = 19; i < 27; i++)
            gpio_write(i, 0);
        for (volatile int delay = 0xF0000; delay != 0; delay--);
        for(i = 10; i < 14 ; i++)
            gpio_write(i, 0);
        for (volatile int delay = 0x0000F; delay != 0; delay--);
    }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL ATTEMPT:**
I tried simplifying the code by not using any functions. Still getting the same result. All segments work on digits 1 and 3. Digits 2 and 4 do not light up.

```
void main(void) {
    // set functions
    unsigned int mask = 7;
    *GP_FSEL1 &= ~((mask)<<(3*1));          // reset pin 11
    *GP_FSEL1 |= GPIO_FUNC_OUTPUT<<(3*1);   // set pin 11 to OUTPUT

    *GP_FSEL2 &= ~((mask)<<(3*0));          // reset pin 20
    *GP_FSEL2 |= GPIO_FUNC_OUTPUT<<(3*0);   // set pin 20 to OUTPUT

    *GP_FSET0 &= ~(1<<11);                  // reset SET Reg of pin 11
    *GP_FSET0 |=   1<<11;                   // set SET Reg of pin 11 to high

    *GP_CLR0 &= ~(1<<20);                   // reset CLR Reg of pin 20
    *GP_CLR0 |=   1<<20;                    // set CLR Reg of pin 20 to high
}
```

Comment: I double checked the addresses against the data sheet. Those are correct.

Comment: Which 7-segment display are you using? Do you have a link for datasheet/user manual?

Comment: KYX-3461BS is the model number, but I couldn't find a Datasheet online

Comment: In your last example you clear pin20. Have you tried to set it instead? Does the same code work for digit 1?

Comment: I just tried this code on digits 1&3. It works for digit 1&3 on all segments as well. I also tried clearing digit pin and setting segment pins, that doesn’t work for any of the digits. Tried setting both digit and segment, that also didn’t work for any of them.

Comment: Have you tried to swap the wires from pin 10 and 11 to the display.

Comment: There are three posibilities: display defect, wiring wrong, software wrong. Using the "simplistic approach" first eliminate hardware and wiring, then look at the software.

Comment: When I swapped the wires of digits 10 & 11 on the RPi, the 2nd digit started working, and the 1st digit stopped working. Then rerouted digit 2 to pin 16. That worked and lit up digit 2 as expected. Then went back to pin 11, rewrote the code to turn it on and checked voltage with a multimeter - 0 volts. Either pin 11 is not working or my code is not activating it properly. I don't see any mistakes in the code. This is a brand new RPi. Any thoughts?

Comment: Currently I am writing the code according to the BCM pin numbers, but I see (according to this site: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin19_gpio10 ) that there are also "wiring pin" numbers and "physical pin" numbers. Could that be a factor somehow?